# How to take screenshot and then click on that saved screenshot in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to click on button on page so I am taking screenshot and trying to click on that screenshot. I need code to take screenshot of particular element and click on that element through code.

Comment: "click on" a screenshot?  What do you mean and what would that accomplish?

Comment: I mean i took screenshot and saved in local directory , now I want to click on that screenshot through my selenium code . can i do that ? And I am doing this because I am not able to click on button normally .

Comment: @RohanDoshi You cannot do that with Selenium.

Comment: I'm curious, what do you think will happen when you click on a PNG that is now totally unrelated to the site that you were automating?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is used to automate only web applications you will not able to perform any operation outside the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Extent report tool for selenium.
If your test fails(Or any condition you set), It call method for taking screenshot and save it to extent report.
At the end of the test, open extent report html file.